# Kotlin/Android, is there any way to simplify multiple resource references?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin, and I've just started refactoring my code.
These parts of my code are painful to look at. Problem is, these are from my resources so I can't really figure out a way to just loop it.

```
paintingList.add(findViewById(R.id.painting1))
paintingList.add(findViewById(R.id.painting2))
paintingList.add(findViewById(R.id.painting3))
paintingList.add(findViewById(R.id.painting4))
paintingList.add(findViewById(R.id.painting5))
paintingList.add(findViewById(R.id.painting6))
```

or

```
when (paintingModels.paintings[i].type) {
1 -> paintingList[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.painting1)
2 -> paintingList[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.painting2)
3 -> paintingList[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.painting3)
4 -> paintingList[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.painting4)
5 -> paintingList[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.painting5)
6 -> paintingList[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.painting6)
                    }
```

What is the way to solve this? Or is this just something that Kotlin devs have to live with?

Answer (score 2):

```
  val resourceIds = listOf(R.id.painting1, R.id.painting2, R.id.painting3)// continue for all resources
```

Or even

```
  val imageViews = listOf(R.id.painting1, R.id.painting2, R.id.painting3).map { findViewById(it) }
```

That would simplify #1

Comment: It would work for #2 as well - make a list of your drawable IDs, then instead of the `when` just grab yr drawable from the list by index, `drawables[type-1]`. (Or maybe make a Map if that makes sense with what you're doing!) Making lists like this is really useful, and it's safer than creating a lookup string since the IDE can help refactor and spot errors, give you previews etc. Sure you have to type each one out, but unless you have a huge number it'll only take a line or two!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
for (i in 1..6) {
    paintingList.add(findViewById(resources.getIdentifier("painting$i", "id", packageName)))
}
```